# Displaying hierarchical data associated with checkboxes in Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, hierarchical-data

Hello and thanks in advance for the assistance,
I have a list of parent objects, in which each parent object has a list of children objects. I would like to display the data in a fashion in which the user may select child objects, press a button and then I will save the selected children objects, along with their parent, likely in xml through serializing the objects with an xml serializer. An idea of what the display should look like is:

```
<sdk:Label x:Name="ParentLabel" content="ParentNameString" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="ChildCheckBox1" Content="ChildNameString" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="ChildCheckBox2" Content="ChildNameString" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="ChildCheckBox3" Content="ChildNameString" />
<sdk:Label x:Name="ParentLabel2" content="ParentNameString" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="ChildCheckBox4" Content="ChildNameString" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="ChildCheckBox5" Content="ChildNameString" />
    <CheckBox x:Name="ChildCheckBox6" Content="ChildNameString" />
```

I know that there are options for a checkbox column in the DataGrid control, but would I be able to display the hierarchical relationship there via Header/children? or is there an option for datatemplating in a Listbox control that would allow headings and associated children elements? What would you recommend?
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: forgive my xaml, I was typing this from the top of my head

Comment: Is this a simple parent / child relationship?  Can the children have children?

Comment: in this case the children wouldn't have children

Comment: I'd probably go with a nested ListBox or TreeView, depending on exactly what you want it to look like.  Set the ItemTemplate of the ListBox/TreeView to another of the same, with it's ItemSource set to Parent.Children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a single level of `Parent` and `Child` you can do something like this.

A simple codebehind with some sample data

```
namespace SilverlightApplication2
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Parent> ParentList { get; set; }

        public MainPage()
        {
            Populate();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Save_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          foreach (var child in ParentList
            .SelectMany(p => p.Children)
            .Where(c => c.IsSelected))
          {
            //Save the child
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Child {0} saved", child.Name));
          }
        }

        private void Populate()
        {
            ParentList = new ObservableCollection<Parent>();
            ParentList.Add(new Parent
            {
                Name = "John",
                Children = new List<Child> { new Child { Name = "Paul" }, new Child { Name = "Pat" } }
            });

            ParentList.Add(new Parent
            {
                Name = "Mike",
                Children = new List<Child> { new Child { Name = "Bob" }, new Child { Name = "Alice" } }
            });

            ParentList.Add(new Parent
            {
                Name = "Smith",
                Children = new List<Child> { new Child { Name = "Ryan" }, new Child { Name = "Sue" }, new Child { Name = "Liz" } }
            });
        }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your xaml would be something like this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.MainPage"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2"
             x:Name="MainUserControl"
             Width="400"
             Height="300"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ChildTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ParentTemplate">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChildTemplate}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainUserControl, Path=ParentList}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ParentTemplate}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

This results in a view like this. I have omitted all styling for simplicity, I am sure you can make it more sexy ;)

[image]

Now you can in the code behind only process `Child` with `IsSelected` true

If you have more than one level... ie..**Your Children have children** you will have to use the [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: wow, thank you this is a complete response. I think this should fit what I need to do. I am currently having some issues with Visual Studio so I am unable to try it out, but I will let you know what my result is. Thanks again for the help.